# Решаю задачу с CodeAbbay номер 4(Min of two). Ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x, min

```py
S_List = []
N = int(input("Количество пар = "))
for i in range(N+1):
    A = (input("Числа = ")).split()
    S_List.append(min(A))
else:
    print("Sums=",' '.join(str(x) for x in S_List))
```

Почему-то из последней пары (а именно 100 и 15) выдаёт 100. Почему?

Ниже представлен ввод в программу

```
Количество пар = 3
Числа = 5 3
Числа = 2 8
Числа = 100 15
Sums= 3 2 100
```

Comment: Это точно работает? Мне что-то подсказывает, что `else` без `if` работать не будет

Comment: @Mattern, это будет работать: `else` в `for` выполнится если в цикле не был вызван `break`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `input` возвращает строку, которая потом разбивается на две строки. При сравнении строк используется лексикографический порядок (упрощенно говоря - алфавитный). Поэтому `'100' < '15'` (точно так же как если бы это были буквы: `'aaa' < 'ab'`).

Перед сравнением введенные строки нужно преобразовать в целые числа, тогда будет сравнивать как числа. Например, так:

```
A = map(int, input("Числа = ").split())
```

Функция `map` применит `int` к каждому элементу переданного ей списка, получится последовательность целых чисел.

Comment: Такой же ответ писал, чуть-чуть не успел ))

Comment: Спасибо большое